# How define two elements with same name with same type in two different position in schema

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a scenario where i have xml schema with same element name with same type at two different positions. Some xml will have the element in first position and few other xml are having the element in the second position.

```
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DisplayUnit" type="DisplayUnit" />
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Serial" type="Serial" />
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DisplayUnit" type="DisplayUnit"/>
```

In my xml some time  DisplayUnit comes above serial and some time after that. How i handle this scenario?

I have one more clarification. In this below scenario the element is not a type but a property. The position can be either above or below output element, but occurs only once like the first scenario.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="MaxA" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="Output" type="Output" />
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MaxA" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
```

I searched a lot but i didn't get any solution.
Any immediate help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts: the XSD part and the parser part.

**XSD**

Your XSD does not fit for the result you want to achieve. As it is written, it is possible that the `DisplayUnit` element occurrs twice in your document. There are two ways to resolve this, depending on your scenario.

If the `DisplayUnit` and `Serial` elements are the only elements in the sequence or the entire sequence can be in any order, you can use `<xs:all>` instead of `<xs:sequence>`. `<xs:all>` allows the elements to be in any order:

```
<xs:all>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DisplayUnit" type="DisplayUnit" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Serial" type="Serial" />
</xs:all>
```

If this is not an option for you, because the other elements are expected to be in sequence, you can replace *that part of the sequence* by an `<xs:choice>`:

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DisplayUnit" type="DisplayUnit" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Serial" type="Serial" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Serial" type="Serial" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DisplayUnit" type="DisplayUnit" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

**Parsing in C#**

Once you have fixed your XSD and you have validated your document, you **know** that there is exactly zero or one occurrence of the `DisplayUnit` and `Serial` tags. Then you can simply load the XML into an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` (if you didn't do that already) and simply access the elements by their name (regardles of order):

```
//Assuming there is an XElement named parentElement
XElement displayUnitElement = parentElement.Element("DisplayUnit");
if (displayUnitElement != null) {
    //...
}
XElement serialElement = parentElement.Element("Serial");
if (serialElement != null) {
    //...
}
```

On more complex XML you can also use XPath. Once your document validates against the XSD, you can be sure about its structure.